# C# Generic class with Interface param

Tags: c#

I tried to create same base generic variable and assign to it every generic object that have param wich inheritance same interface , but I got an error "Cannot implicitly convert type".
Can some help me understand this ?

```
public interface ISomthink
{

}
public class Somethink: ISomthink
{

}
public class Somethink2: ISomthink
{

}
public class MyGeneric<T> where T:ISomthink
{

}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISomthink s1 = null;
        s1=new Somethink();
        s1 = new Somethink2();

        MyGeneric<ISomthink> sg = null;
        sg=new MyGeneric<Somethink>();//Error Cannot implicitly convert type
        sg = new MyGeneric<Somethink2>();//Error Cannot implicitly convert type

    }
}
```

Comment: C# doesn't work that way. You can only assign `MyGeneric<ISomthink>` instances to `sg`, or an instance of a type that *inherits* from `MyGeneric<ISomthink>`. Even though `Somethink` implements `ISomthink`, `MyGeneric<Somethink>` does *not* **inherit** from `MyGeneric<ISomthink>`.

Comment: Take a look at [variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/), specifically the [out keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) may be of interest to you.

Comment: best bet is to add ```public interface IMyGeneric<out T> where T : ISomthink { }``` and ```public class MyGeneric<T> : IMyGeneric<T> where T : ISomthink { }```  then do  ```IMyGeneric<ISomthink> sg = null;```